# Kafka Streams - Aggregation with old state

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a **KStream** with data from topic **to1** like this:

```
T1-KEY -> {T1}
T2-KEY -> {T2}
```

and a **KTable**, constructed as follows:

I am using *org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder* to create the **KTable** from some topic **to2** which looks like this:

```
A1-KEY -> { "A1", "Set": [
                          {"B1", "Rel": "T1"},
                          {"B2", "Rel": "T1"}
                         ]
          } 

..
```

The stream is then being flatmapped and grouped by Key s.t. the resulting **KTable** looks like this:

```
T1 -> { ["B1", "B2"] }
```

At a later time, now the following message occurs in topic **to2**:

```
A1-KEY -> { "A1", "Set": [
                          {"B2", "Rel": "T1"}
                         ]
          }
```

Now I would expect my **KTable** to reflect the changes and look like this:

```
T1 -> { ["B2"] }
```

but it looks like this:

```
T1 -> { ["B1", "B2"] }
```

I noticed, that in my `Aggregator<Tx-KEY, Bx, Set<Bx>>` the last argument given is the set `["B1", "B2"]` even though when I peek before aggregating I only get one match `"B2"`.

Am I understanding the aggregation wrong or what is happening here?

**EDIT**

I think I narrowed it down: Apparently the aggregation's `Initializer` is only called for the *very* first time - after that the aggregate always receives the `last aggregate` as last argument, e.g.

```
@Override
public Set<Bx> apply(Tx-KEY, Bx value, Set<Bx> aggregate) {

}
```

where `Set<Bx> aggregate` is `[]` on the very first call (created via the initializer) but `["B1", "B2"]` for the second call.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

```
public class MyAggregator implements Aggregator<Tx-KEY, Bx, Set<Bx>> {

    @Override
    public Set<Bx> apply(Tx-KEY key, Bx value, Set<Bx> aggregate) {
        aggregate.add(value);
        return aggregate;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

I cant only flat map though, as I have to combine multiple Ax elements, e.g.

```
A1-KEY -> { "A1", "Set": [
                      {"B1", "Rel": "T1"}
                     ]
          },
A2-KEY -> { "A2", "Set": [
                      {"B2", "Rel": "T1"}
                     ]
          },
...
```

where I then expect some group by like

```
T1 -> { ["B1", "B2"] }
```

and in the next iteration, when the message

```
A1-KEY -> { "A1", "Set": [
                      {"B1", "Rel": "T1"}
                     ]
          }
```

arrives I'd expected

```
T1 -> { ["B1"] }
```

..

Comment: Please provide your code, especially for your aggregator's apply method. What you wrote in the edit is correct. The Initializer, as the name suggests, is only used to initialize, later the result is passed on and given in the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the apply function above. I do want to have a new set there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how in your aggregator you are only ever adding elements to the aggregate set. With this logic, your set (for a given key) can never shrink. I think you have flattened the stream too much in this case. I suggest you don't flatten it to the point your messages are of the form `(Tx-KEY key, Bx value)` but instead so that they always retain their set form: `(Tx-KEY key, Set<Bx> value)`. You don't need the aggregation then at all.
To achieve that I suggest you transform the input set

```
"Set": [
     {"B1", "Rel": "T1"},
     {"B2", "Rel": "T1"}
]
```

into

```
T1 -> { ["B1", "B2"] }
```

by grouping by the "Rel" field using standard java code (Collections or Streams api) inside the KStream flatmap method call so that you are only ever emitting messages with `Set<Bx>`-typed values on the KStream, not `Bx`-typed values individually.

Happy to elaborate more if you provide the code for your current flatmap implementation.

Comment: `Notice how in your aggregator you are only ever adding elements to the aggregate set. With this logic, your set (for a given key) can never shrink.` Yes, that was due to my misunderstanding of the initializer. I added a third edit above as your proposed solution does not meet my requirements yet.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "in the next iteration". What iterations are you referring to? Is there a way to determine the iteration number from the message? I suspect you may need to use a more sophisticated structure than a Set, to be able to capture that information as well but need more high-level info about your use case to understand fully as currently your requirements sound contradictory to someone not familiar with your use case.

Comment: Whatever marks the beginning of a new iteration, if you can detect it in the aggregator function, you can then empty the set before putting new elements into it.

Comment: Yes, thats what is required. I have to be able to notice where I have to read the other stream from (offset start and offset end). Thank you for your help!